# Project is integrated with angular 6 with jest framework ,npm test throwing error

Tags: angular, jestjs

On npm test login.component.spec.ts 
it gives following error:

> Project 'login.component.spec.ts' could not be found in workspace.
>   Error: Project 'login.component.spec.ts' could not be found in
>   workspace.

Comment: Its a file not found error, Please make sure you are running it from correct path !

Comment: it works fine when running  'npm test' ,but it gives an error while running particular spec file

Comment: yeah you need to point to file's absolute path first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

`npm test -- --test-match **/login.component.spec.ts`

Comment: Thanks, It worked!, but what changes i can do in my config file to make 'npm test login.component.spec.ts'  to work